# Symfony: can't enable custom repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to use a custom repository for my symfony 2.8 website:

Custom repository:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/ExperimentationRepository
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ExperimentationRepository extends EntityRepository
{    
    public function getExperimentationByUser($id){
        // do stuff and return results
    }    
}
```

Entity:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Experimentation
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Experimentation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="experimentation")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ExperimentationRepository")
 */
class Experimentation{
   // sutff
}
```

Controller (where I try to use the custom repository, in another bundle):

```
// src/ManageBundle/Controller/ManageController
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$experimentations = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Experimentation')->getExperimentationByUser($id);
```

I got the following error:

> Undefined method 'getExperimentationByUser'. 
>       The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

After some research, I've tried to check if my custom repository was called or not:

```
$repository=$this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Experimentation');
        $repositoryClass=get_class($repository);
echo $repositoryClass;
exit;
```

Which returns:

```
Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
```

So I guess my custom repository isn't called at all. But I can't manage to find why. I've tried several actions (after some digging):

- clear the cache (`app/console cache:clear`)
- clear doctrine cache (`app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`)
- check config.yml (under doctrine:orm): `auto_mapping: true`
- check config.yml (under doctrine:dbal): `type: annotation`
- I don't have any config/doctrine folder (is that normal?)

Nothing worked. Still got the same error. It's look like the framework completely ignore the annotation in the entity class. Any idea/suggestion?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you generated entities?

Comment: Quite a mystery.  You only have one entity manager defined?  I suspect a simple typo somewhere.  Does app/console doctrine:mapping:info pick up the entity?  And yes it is normal to have config/doctrine to be empty when using annotations.  config/doctrine is where yaml or xml mapping files normally live.  In fact if you had files there then the annotations would be ignored.

Comment: Entities are generated. `app/console doctrine:mapping:info` picks all of them with the "OK" tag.

Comment: Try once to change your entity annotation to `ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Test")`. You should get a fatal error: `Fatal error: Class 'Test' not found in...` If you don't get this error then the annotation is not read correctly.

Comment: Grasping for straws here.  Are you positive you have edited the correct Experimentation.php file?  I have sometimes gotten confused and edited a completely different file in a different project or have forgotten to save my changes.  Have you checked your code into github?  I'll take a look if you have.  Got to be a simple config error somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to make it work. After several commands, I've managed to create the `AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine file`. It was full of `.orm.xml` files, so I just took the XML syntax from the doc:

```
  <entity
     name="AppBundle\Entity\Experimentation"
     repository-class="AppBundle\Entity\ExperimentationRepository">
```

However, I still don't understand why the annotation system is not working, since I've tried so hard to enable it. Is there at least a way to check what system (XML, YAML or Annotation) is enabled? Feel free to comment if you have a clue...

Comment: In your original question you said you checked config/doctrine?  Did you also check AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine.  If you had files there then that would explain why the annotations were being ignored.

Comment: That is exactly what happen. Will annotation be considered if I delete those files?

Comment: It seems you created these xmls yourself by not using annotation format in initially importing via shell ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like that:

```
// src/ManageBundle/Controller/ManageController

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Experimentation');
$experimentations = $repository->getExperimentationByUser($id);
```

And generate entity

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Experimentation
```

Comment: Yes I tried to generate entities. Everything looks fine, except that it does not work when loading the page. I tried your code, even if it's exactly the same as mine (you just add a repository var in the middle) ; it doesn't solve it neither. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You just delete cache folder. clear cache with CLI command didn't work for me. `php app/console cache:clear`